# Label is not becoming active for select box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I click on **select box**, `label` is not becoming active. In input boxes, it's working fine.

Is it possible for select box also ? If not, please tell me another method to make it active.

[When I click on input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFP31.png)

[When I click on select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7B3q.png)

**Here is the code:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="customModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='cname'>Class Name</label>
           <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cname' id='cname' required>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='' class="">Class Incharge</label>
              <select class="myselect" style="border-width:none; width:100%;" >
                <option hidden selected disabled></option>
                <option>Sahal EV</option>
                <option>Muhammed Rahil</option>
                <option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option>
                <option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='tkno'>Token Number</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='tkno' id='tkno' readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class='form-group'>
              <label for='cap'>Capacity</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cap' id='cap'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="saveClass">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Placeholder or Label?

Comment: @Vishnu ya, Sorry..I mean Label

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this JS. I just added `.lab-active` class for input & select fields. When the field is focused, it should be add a class into the `label`

```js
$(".form-group .lab-active").focus(function() {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
}).blur(function() {
  $("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
});
```

```css
.labelfocus {
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="customModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='cname'>Class Name</label>
           <input type='text' class='form-control lab-active' name='cname' id='cname' required>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='' class="">Class Incharge</label>
              <select class="myselect lab-active" style="border-width:none; width:100%;" >
                <option hidden selected disabled></option>
                <option>Sahal EV</option>
                <option>Muhammed Rahil</option>
                <option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option>
                <option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='tkno'>Token Number</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control lab-active' name='tkno' id='tkno' readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class='form-group'>
              <label for='cap'>Capacity</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control lab-active' name='cap' id='cap'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="saveClass">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. You have to define label for like `<label for='class-incharge'>` and then you have to give the  same id to `select` tag and class **`form-control`** also remained to be added.
like

```
<select class="myselect form-control" id="class-incharge" style="border-width:none; width:100%;" >
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="customModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='cname'>Class Name</label>
           <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cname' id='cname' required>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='class-incharge' class="">Class Incharge</label>
              <select class="myselect form-control" id="class-incharge" style="border-width:none; width:100%;" >
                <option hidden selected disabled></option>
                <option>Sahal EV</option>
                <option>Muhammed Rahil</option>
                <option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option>
                <option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='tkno'>Token Number</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='tkno' id='tkno' readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class='form-group'>
              <label for='cap'>Capacity</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cap' id='cap'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="saveClass">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just replace this code from `<div class="modal fade"` line.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="customModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='cname'>Class Name</label>
           <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cname' id='cname' required>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='class-incharge' class="">Class Incharge</label>
              <select class="myselect form-control" id="class-incharge" style="border-width:none; width:100%;" >
                <option hidden selected disabled></option>
                <option>Sahal EV</option>
                <option>Muhammed Rahil</option>
                <option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option>
                <option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback is-empty">
              <label for='tkno'>Token Number</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='tkno' id='tkno' readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class='form-group'>
              <label for='cap'>Capacity</label>
              <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cap' id='cap'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" id="saveClass">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sidharth run my snippet you will find your answer

Comment: show your full code with your modal button so I can help you

Comment: But its not Working in my Code

Comment: Its big code, Modal is opened using jquery. It contains many other coding also.Fully mixed up

Comment: @Sidharth just replace your code with my updated answer

Comment: I'm unable to add my code in comment, its very lengthy

Comment: We can chat in the chat room and discuss your problem or on skype this my skype id: chirag.patel2595

Comment: Can u check it by using TeamViewer

Comment: sure tell me your team viewer id

Comment: ID: 273 597 248 Password: 5256

Comment: tell me the password?

Comment: Password : 5256

Answer (score 0):

Js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".form-control.lab-active").focus(function() {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
}).blur(function() {
  $("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
});
});
```

Css:

```
.labelfocus {
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Also add lab-active class to all input and select tag.